# DotNet Core app doesn't accept POST on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

This is my first DotNetCore 2.0 app, which I want to use to compare performance between IIS/Windows and nginx/Ubuntu. It is an app that talks to a number of services (mongo/redis/session state) to create a fake but realistic user journey.

The app runs absolutely fine on Windows, when debugging from Visual Studio or when invoked from PostMan BUT, if I deploy to Ubuntu, although I can access the front page of the site and the next page (both GET), as soon as I POST the form on the second page (just a single field), it fails from browser and postman with a 400 but no details. Ubuntu is not logging anything other than the web server starting, although it has logged errors previously so logging is working.

I even tried `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` on the action but that didn't help.

Relevant config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("useFileSystem"))
    {
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration.GetValue<string>("fileSystemPersistPath")))
            .SetApplicationName("Perftest2018");
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("Perftest2018");
    }

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });

    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });

    //<snip> the rest of my services
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default",template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The action is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(AuthorizeViewModel model)
{
    // The view model just has a single string property with no other attributes
}
```

Comment: 400 means Bad Request, ie the request you made was bad. Are you sure `nginx` didn't just reject it?

Comment: Because when the app threw before, it logged the error in my error log? Could it be throwing and killing the log output? Possibly but that doesn't explain why it doesn't work. nginx is not rejecting it, it is a proxy to dotnetcore and the other pages are working.

Comment: Looking at another question, is it possibly something to do with POST being prevented somewhere over HTTP instead of HTTPS? I can see how to enable this but not that it is enabled anywhere by default.

Comment: Are you missing the [FromBody] decorator on your POST method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by additional nginx headers in the proxy that were taken from another server running with TLS. The headers `Upgrade $http_upgrade` and `Connection "upgrade"` were presumably not permitting POST!

Comment: thx Lukos i also ran into this issue and like you suspected nginx was to blame as it worked fine on windows and logging the request indicated it never made it to the controller. i'm guessing that these extra headers cause kestrel to wig out - it seems these headers are required only if you're going to use websockets see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: after reading the [dotnet core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2) it appears the `Connection "upgrade"` is the cause